# Get pixel values in local area under center-pixel's gradient direction

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How to get pixel values in local area under center-pixel's gradient direction using matlab?

I already found function imgradient() that's good, but how to transform angle to line under this angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to know how to define a line given a point `(x0,y0)` and an angle `theta`? Something like this perhaps:

```
% T determines the length of the line. I am using a step size
% of 0.5 since it should get each pixel. You could always go finer
% and let the call to unique get rid of the duplicates.
t = 0:0.5:T;
p = unique( round( [x0+t(:)*cos(theta), y0+t(:)*sin(theta) ] ), 'rows' );
```

`p` in the above will be a Nx2 array of pixel coordinates that are under (technically within 1/2 a pixel) of the line that starts at `(x0,y0)` and extends out an angle `theta`.